# How do I fill the other part of this svg with a different color so it blends in with my design?

Tags: html, css, svg

How do I fill the other part of this svg with a different color so it blends in with my design? I want to fill the white part with the same grey that is above the curved svg, is that possible and how would I be able to achieve this?

Here is the svg:

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 160 1440 100"><path fill="#F43C58" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,160L80,181.3C160,203,320,245,480,240C640,235,800,181,960,165.3C1120,149,1280,171,1360,181.3L1440,192L1440,320L1360,320C1280,320,1120,320,960,320C800,320,640,320,480,320C320,320,160,320,80,320L0,320Z" data-darkreader-inline-fill="" style="--darkreader-inline-fill:#F43C58;"></path></svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 160 1440 100" viewport-fill="blue" style='stroke-width: 0px; background-color: blue;'><path fill="#F43C58" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,160L80,181.3C160,203,320,245,480,240C640,235,800,181,960,165.3C1120,149,1280,171,1360,181.3L1440,192L1440,320L1360,320C1280,320,1120,320,960,320C800,320,640,320,480,320C320,320,160,320,80,320L0,320Z" data-darkreader-inline-fill="" style="--darkreader-inline-fill:#F43C58;" ></path></svg>
```

to fill background with a `blue` color.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the SVG a background color:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 160 1440 100" style="background: #ecf0f3;"><path fill="#F43C58" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,160L80,181.3C160,203,320,245,480,240C640,235,800,181,960,165.3C1120,149,1280,171,1360,181.3L1440,192L1440,320L1360,320C1280,320,1120,320,960,320C800,320,640,320,480,320C320,320,160,320,80,320L0,320Z" data-darkreader-inline-fill="" style="--darkreader-inline-fill:#F43C58;background: #000;"></path></svg>
```